# C# : Common method/wrapper for methods with different definitions

Tags: c#, delegates, func

For example, I have the following methods:

```
    private async Task<T> Read<T>(string id, string endpoint)
    {
         //....
    }

    private async Task<List<T>> List<T>(int start, int count, string endpoint, List<FilterData> filterData = null)
    {
         //....
    }
```

(and more with different properties)
But all of these method can throw `BillComInvalidSessionException`
If I called method throws this exception, I want to execute some logic and recall called method. 
I.e.:

```
    private async Task<T> ReadWithRetry<T>(string id, string endpoint)
    {
        try
        {
            return await Read<T>(id, endpoint);
        }
        catch (BillComInvalidSessionException)
        {
            SessionId = new Lazy<string>(() => LoginAsync().Result);
            return await ReadWithRetry<T>(id, endpoint);
        }
    }

    private async Task<List<T>> ListWithRetry<T>(int start, int count, string endpoint, List<FilterData> filterData = null)
    {
        try
        {
            return await List<T>(start, count, endpoint, filterData);
        }
        catch (BillComInvalidSessionException)
        {
            SessionId = new Lazy<string>(() => LoginAsync().Result);
            return await ListWithRetry<T>(start, count, endpoint, filterData);
        }
    }
```

How to create one common method, which will execute the same logic, but get different methods as parameters?

Comment: I don’t know how you’d do it, maybe if you changed each method to take an object array they’d all have the same signature, but you’d be boxing/unboxing the parameters all the time and would have to do all the validation checks that each one is the correct type so I don’t know if that’s more or less work than just doing what you have.

Comment: @Neil.Work right now I have "copy/paste" code. Seems, I can implement it with Func<...>, but can't understand how to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a generic delegate:

```
private async Task<T> Retry<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
{
    try
    {
        return await func();
    }
    catch (BillComInvalidSessionException)
    {
        SessionId = new Lazy<string>(() => LoginAsync().Result);
        return await Retry(func);
    }
}
```

And then your retry methods would turn to:

```
private async Task<T> ReadWithRetry<T>(string id, string endpoint)
{
    return await Retry(async () => await Read<T>(id, endpoint));
}

private async Task<List<T>> ListWithRetry<T>(int start, int count, string endpoint, List<FilterData> filterData = null)
{
    return await Retry(async () => await List<T>(start, count, endpoint, filterData));
}
```

Comment: why did you add `static` for methods?

Comment: I had them as static since I had it in a console app. I just removed the static modifiers since they're not necessary and to avoid confusion